# Mysql query for insert records from csv file to mysql Db

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, csv

I am trying to insert data from `csv` file to `mysql` database. Data is inserted to DB. But not in the way I expected. In my case there are several `text` files which includes `employee id`, `date`, `in time` and `out time`. Also, I want to validate this if there is one record for the same employee number with same date it should not allow to insert the any data.

**My Code**

```
$fdate = array_filter(explode(" ", $y));

$csv->emp_id = $epf;
$a_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fdate[9]));
$csv->date= $a_date;

$csv->save();

$check = "SELECT * FROM daily_attendances WHERE emp_id = $epf AND date = '$a_date'";

$sql = DB::select(DB::raw($check));
$count = count($sql);

if($count > 0){
  if ($fdate[11] == "AM") {
        $update_query = "UPDATE daily_attendances SET in_time = '$fdate[10]'  WHERE 
       emp_id = $epf AND date = '$a_date'";
       $sql = DB::select(DB::raw($update_query));

                            } elseif ($fdate[11] == "PM") {
                                $o_time = date("H:i:s", strtotime($fdate[10] . $fdate[11]));
                                $update_query = "UPDATE daily_attendances SET out_time = '$o_time'  WHERE emp_id = $epf AND date = '$a_date'";
                                $sql = DB::select(DB::raw($update_query));


                            }
```

current output

[image]

expected output
[image]

Comment: Removal of duplicates should probably be done in the database, after you have loaded the CSV data.

Comment: I don't understand your expected output.  Whence is the timestamp `18:18:21`?  It appears in neither of the two original rows.

Comment: Please add your `csv` data structure in file.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i have edited the question

Comment: What value gets inserted for the `id` in this case?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it is auto incremented value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend loading the CSV data into a temporary table first using MySQL's `LOAD DATA`.  Once you have done that, you can insert into your target `daily_attendances` table using a query along the lines of the following:

```
INSERT INTO daily_attendances (emp_id, date, in_time, out_time)
SELECT emp_id, date, MAX(in_time), MAX(out_time)
FROM temp
GROUP BY emp_id, date
```

This answer assumes that the only sort of duplication or missing data is what you showed us in the question.  In general, bringing in lots of new data from CSV will be fastest with `LOAD DATA`.  Also, the kind of logic you require to scrub your data should be handled in the database.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to check by using **SQL** query.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_2 (id, name) SELECT t1.id,t1.name
FROM TABLE_1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT id FROM TABLE_2 t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id)
```